# How to add new tabs to a TabControl and be able to update controls in them?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tabs, tabcontrol

I need to be able to programmatically create new tabs on a TabControl, add controls to them, and be able to update the controls in each tab from another function. I already have a function to add tabs to the control, and to add controls to those tabs when they are created, but I'm stuck as to update the controls after they have been created.

EDIT: This is what I have to make the tabs and add the controls:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim tabpage As New TabPage
    tabpage.Text = "(empty)"

    Dim textbox1 As New TextBox
    Dim textbox2 As New TextBox

    textbox1.Parent = tabpage
    textbox2.Parent = tabpage

    textbox1.Location = New Point(10, 10)
    textbox2.Location = New Point(10, 30)

    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabpage)

End Sub
```

---

Urgh. I can't seem to get back into the account I used to post this question, so I have to post my follow-up to Tim's question in the comments for the previous answer as a new answer.
`Debug.WriteLine(TabControl1.TabPages.Item(2).Controls.Find("textbox1", True).Count)` returns 0. The tab and the controls have been created prior.

Comment: Posting the code you currently have will enable other programmers to give you a more definitive answer.  Generally I'd think you'd be able to simply reference the control(s) in question through the tab container, but I don't do WinForms very often, and haven't used the Tab control since .NET 1.0.

Comment: I updated the post with the code I have. Comments don't like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - I'll give it a shot, but I'm real rusty with WinForms, slightly less rusty with VB.NET.  You'll need to locate the control you want to update, and you should be able to do that through the `Controls` collection of the appropriate container - in this case, most likely a `TabPage`:

```
TextBox tb1 = CType(tabpage.Controls.Find("textBox1", false), TextBox)
tb1.Text = "I set the text!"
```

Syntax might be slightly off, but hopefully this will at least point you in the right direction.

See [Control.ControlCollection.Find Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

**UPDATED**

Hans Passant suggested that this isn't working because you didn't set the `Name` property (I'm assuming he means the name of the controls, not the tab page).  I did a little more reading on the `ControlsCollection.Find` method, and MSDN says "Searches for controls by their Name property and builds an array of all the controls that match."  You (and I) were trying to find the control by the instance name (textbox1, textbox2) - which were the **instance** names for the two controls, not the control **names**.

So try this instead:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim tabpage As New TabPage
    tabpage.Text = "(empty)"

    Dim textbox1 As New TextBox
    Dim textbox2 As New TextBox

    textbox1.Parent = tabpage
    textbox2.Parent = tabpage

    textbox1.Location = New Point(10, 10)
    textbox2.Location = New Point(10, 30)

    textbox1.Name = "textbox1"
    textbox2.Name = "textbox2"

    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabpage)

End Sub
```

Then you can find the control using:

```
TextBox tb1 = CType(TabControl1.TabPages.Item(TabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1).Controls.Find("textbox1", True)(0), TextBox) 
tb1.text = "Test"
```

Give that a try and see if it works for you.  The key (and what I missed looking at your code last night as it was past my bedtime for me) was there was now way to identify the control in the `Find` method.

Comment: I just tried this:
`Dim tb1 As TextBox = CType(TabControl1.TabPages.Item(TabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1).Controls.Find("textbox1", True)(0), TextBox)`
`tb1.text = "Test"` and I get an IndexOutOfRange exception. Unsure why, it can't seem to find the textbox there?

Comment: Step through your code in the debugger, and before the CType line check the values for both `TabControl1.TabPages.Count` and the `.Controls.Find("textBox1", True)` to see how many elements are in the ControlsCollection.  Also check your spelling of the control ID - not sure if VB.Net is case-sensitive or not on IDs.

Comment: `Debug.WriteLine("TabControl1.TabPages.Count: " & TabControl1.TabPages.Count) ` and `Debug.WriteLine("Control count: " & TabControl1.Controls.Find("textbox1", True).Count)` returned this:
TabControl1.TabPages.Count: 3
Control count: 0

The case is correct, and I'm still unsure as to why it is not returning anything.

Comment: How many controls total are on that `TabPage`?  Check `.Controls.Count`.  Has the `TabPage` and controls in question been created prior to this part of the code?  (I assume they have, just checking the obvious).

Comment: @Hans Passant - Doh!  Thanks for pointing that out.  You should post it as an answer so you can get the credit for it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but just an opinion, write a function that creates AND returns the control you want to add to the tabpage. In that case, you will have a reference to the control ready at hand. 
For example:

```
Public Function CreateNewListBoxInsideNewPageTab() As ListBox
        Dim newTab As New TabPage()
        newTab.Text = "Tab " & TabControl1.TabPages.Count + 1

        Dim newLst As New ListBox
        newLst.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

        newTab.Controls.Add(newLst)
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add(newTab)
        TabControl1.SelectedTab = newTab
        Return newLst
    End Function
```

Now when I call this function, I'll have the new listbox as an object:

```
Dim newListBox as ListBox = CreateNewListBoxInsideNewPageTab()
newListBox.Items.Add("This is a new listbox item!")
```

Answer (score 0):

can i add tabcontroll elements after programm started?

```
  For i = 0 To frmMain.cmbZielSpache.Items.Count - 1

        Dim cBox = New CheckBox()
        cBox.Name = "GEN_" & i
        cBox.Location = New Point(offsetX, offsetY)
        cBox.Text = frmMain.cmbZielSpache.Items(i)

        If frmMain.cmbZielSpache.Items(i) = frmMain.cmbZielSpache.Text Or My.Settings.chkTranslate_normal_alleSprachen = True Then
            cBox.Checked = True
        End If

        offsetX = offsetX + 120

        Me.Controls.Add(cBox)
        AddHandler cBox.CheckedChanged, AddressOf checkChangedHandler

    Next i
```

Instead of using Me.Controls i wanna add the checkboxes after programm started dynamically.